# Convolution with Gaussian, without distribution theory, part 1

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, normal-distribution, lp-spaces, gaussian-integral

I only know basic $L^p$ theory (nothing about distributions) and am trying to prove the following:

Let $t>0$, $f\in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^n,m)$, $\Gamma(t,x)=(4\pi t)^{-n/2}e^{-|x|^2/4t}$ and
$$
u(t,x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Gamma(t,x-y)f(y)dy.
$$

If $1\leq p<\infty$, then $u(t,\cdot)\to f$ in $L^p$ as $t\to 0$.

(EDIT: I've asked the original parts [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182678/convolution-with-gaussian-without-distribution-theory-part-2) and [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182683/convolution-with-gaussian-without-dstributioni-theory-part-3) as separate questions.)

I've shown that $||u(t,\cdot)||_p\leq ||f||_p$ for $1\leq p\le\infty$ but haven't gotten anywhere from here. Could someone please give some hints or suggest a reference (these seem to be very well-known and widely applicable results).

Comment: Are you sure it is $e^{-x^2/(4t)}$ not $e^{-|x|^2/(4t)}$ ?

Comment: I'm sure you're right, thanks for the correction!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: (Just getting the facts straight: I was NOT the one who downvoted science's answer below, but I'm trying to do this without any use of distribution theory.) Any hints would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) We notice first that

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \Gamma(t,x) dx = 1\; \forall t \in \mathbb{R}_{+} $$

And, as $t \rightarrow 0$, $\Gamma(t,x) \rightarrow 0, \; x \not=0$, so that, by the Dominated Convergence Theorem, $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n\backslash B(0,\delta)} \Gamma(t,x) dx \rightarrow 0 \;\forall \delta > 0$ as $t \rightarrow 0$. This will help us now:

Write

$$\| u(t,\cdot) - f\|_p^p = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Gamma(t,y)[f(x-y)-f(x)]dy\right|^pdx $$

By Minkowski's inequality for integrals, we've that

$$\|u(x,\cdot)-f\|_p \le \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}  |f(x-y)-f(x)|^p dx\right) ^{1/p}\Gamma(t,y) dy\;\;\;\;(1) $$

Now we'll need a

> **Lemma**: The translation is continuous in $L^p$, i.e., for each $f \in L^P$, we've that
>
> $$\|\tau_hf - f \|_p \rightarrow 0$$
>
> As $h \rightarrow 0$

The proof of this Lemma is a standard one: frist, we show that it is true for $f \in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then approximate any $L^p$ functions by functions of this kind. I won't provide details for this proof here.

So, now we've that

$$\|u(t,\cdot)-f\|_p \le \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \|\tau_y f - f\|_p \Gamma(t,y)dy \\ \le \int_{B(0,\delta)}\|\tau_y f - f\|_p \Gamma(t,y)dy + 2\|f\|_p \int_{B(0,\delta)^{c}}\Gamma(t,y)dy $$

By the observations and the Lemma, we've that we may choose $\delta$ such that $\|\tau_y f - f \|_p \le \epsilon \;\forall |y|<\delta$, and, for this $\delta$, if we make $t$ sufficiently small, we'll have that the second integral is littler than or equal to $\epsilon$, so that, for small enough $t$,

$$ \|u(t,\cdot) - f\|_p \le \epsilon + 2\|f\|_p\;\epsilon$$

This Clearly finishes the proof of (1).

(2) **EDIT**: There was a mistake in this part, as @robjohn mentioned. I think this one is right: Let $f \in L^1\cap L^p$ at first. Then, by the Young's inequality,

$$ \|u(t,\cdot)\|_{\infty} \le \|\Gamma(t,\cdot)\|_{p'} \|f\|_p $$

And

$$ \|u(t,\cdot)\|_{1} \le \|f\|_1 $$

By $L^p$-Interpolation, we've that

$$ \|u(t,\cdot)\|_p \le \|u(t,\cdot)\|_1^{1/p}\|u(t,\cdot)\|_{\infty}^{(p-1)/p}\le C(f,p)\|\Gamma(t,\cdot)\|_{p'} ^{(p-1)/p} $$

Where $p'^{-1} + p^{-1} = 1$. But

$$\|\Gamma(t,\cdot)\|_{r}^r = \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{nr/2}}\int e^{\frac{-r|x|^2}{4t}}dx = \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{nr/2}} c(n) \int_{0}^{\infty} s^{n-1}e^{-\frac{rs^2}{4t}}ds = \\ \frac{c(n)}{(4\pi t)^{nr/2}} \sqrt{\frac{4t}{r}}^n \int_0^{\infty} w^{n-1}e^{-w^2} dw $$

Which shows that, for $r>1$, $\|\Gamma(t,\cdot)\|_r \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$. Thus, we've proved the Theorem for $f \in L^1 \cap L^p$.

For the general case, let $g \in L^1\cap L^p$ be such that $\|g-f\|_p \le \varepsilon$, and then

$$ \|u_f(t,\cdot)\|_p \le \|u_g(t,\cdot)-u_f(t,\cdot)\|_p + \|u_g(t,\cdot)\|_p \le \varepsilon + \varepsilon$$

If $t$ is big enough, where we've used once again that $\|u(t,\cdot)\|_p\le \|f\|_p$. So, the Theorem is proved.

Part (3) is lengthier than the previous one. The shortest proof I know to this fact uses that the convolution type Operator associated to the Gaussian is of Weak type 1-1 and dominated by a multiple of the Hardy-Littlewood Maximal Operator, but, as you said your background is of only $L^p$ spaces, then I suppose this is too complicated for this discussion.

Comment: The continuity lemma for $L^p$ only holds for $p\lt\infty$. I know it's a prerequisite for (1), but it should probably be mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, Yeah, I should note that I was assuming $p < \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

You need the fact

$$ \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}} e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}} = \delta(x) $$

where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta function.

Comment: Thanks, but this is supposed to be an exercise not assuming any knowledge of distribution theory; and you may well assume that in fact I don't know any yet. So basic $L^p$ theory and inequalities are my only tools, unfortunately.

Comment: @Aubrey: I can see the tag of distribution theory!

Comment: Would you care explaining what is the down vote for? The OP changed the title and the tag after I submitted my answer!

Comment: Still though, it might be better if you could perhaps remove the answer, since the question hasn't really been answered?

Comment: I don't think that's how it works. science's answer is technically valid given that the answer was edited after the fact. You can still wait for another answer though. I'd be wary of answering given that I suspect the asker gave a downvote in this situation. The error was the asker's not the answerer's. And the answer is valid (I haven't checked the math) given the state of the question at the time.

Comment: @jdods Of course the OP has not downvoted (and hadn't even bothered to mention this, until you mistakenly suspected otherwise). (It doesn't really matter, but I probably should say that, even though I had initially included the distribution tag, the statement "I know only basic $L^p$ theory (nothing about distributions)" was there from the start. At first I had included the distribution theory tag thinking that someone with knowledge of the theory is also likely to come up with a more elementary and laborious argument that doesn't depend on the theory).

Comment: @jdods (My "yes" above was a response to science's comment about the distribution tag, not about the downvote, which occured when I was sleeping.)

Comment: I believe it was reasonable to suspect you are the one who gave the down vote on the answer, especially given that you asked to have the answer deleted. If you did not give the down vote, I apologize for the suspicion! Maybe science's math was wrong or irrelevant,  and that's why someone downvoted the answer. I did understand what the "yes" was for. Probably science's suspicion of the downvote influenced my suspicion. Really, not a big deal.

Comment: @jdods Do you think I could post this question again as new? The issue now is that it appears that an answer has been posted, but unfortunately it is actually irrelevant (though correct).

Comment: That's not something I can answer for you as I'm fairly new here. You can go over to http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/ to ask that. However, multiple answers are allowed to be given. I have added a new answer on several occasions, if I feel like I have insight to offer. Many (probably most) questions receive multiple answers. This thread is yours; you own it, so to speak. So you can delete it if you like (I think) and re-ask it, but I personally think it is better to leave it (for transparency) and just edit the question appropriately. Another thing you can ask over on meta.

Comment: @Aubrey: A friendly piece of advice from a friendly moderator. You have some false impressions about how the site works. It often happens here that somebody answers a question using tools that the original asker is unfamiliar with. BECAUSE THE ANSWERS ARE NOT ONLY FOR YOU BUT ALSO FOR FUTURE VISITORS WHO HAVE A SIMILAR QUESTION, we view this as one of the **strengths** of the site.  Just wait for another answer!

Comment: @Jyrki I completely agree with what you said, but actually my point is not only that the answer uses tools that the OP is unfamliar with, or even worse, that the OP explicitly asks not to be used: The above response is not really an answer at all, because essentially it merely restates the claim to be proved (in the language of distribution theory). Thus the question seems to be answered, even though this is not the case at all.  The "fact that I need" is basically my question.